# Calculate throughput when downloading a file?

Tags: file, upload, download, calculator, throughput

By downloading and uploading 5MB, 10MB, 20MB, 50MB, and 100MB files. How can the throughput be calculated?

thanks,

Comment: Throughput = Size / Time, what's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I have t calculate the throughput of files being downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
throughput = bytes_downloaded / (time_now - time_started);
```

If that's not enough to solve the problem, you need to be much more detailed in your question. Post the code you've written so far, and explain why it isn't working.

Comment: My task is to measure the throughput of a wireless LAN. I should include in my report:
1) Description of the experiment setup, e.g. the make/model/standard of client and access point, software and method for performing the experiments.
2) Results of the experiments in table or plots.
3)Explanation of the results, that is, why the results are as you measured.